# Suspense feature of vue3 not working as expected with nested routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am going to use a [suspense feature](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html) provided by Vue (experimental, I know).
I have found that it's not working as expected in the case when I use it with nested router views. The parent `router-view` has an inner `router-view` to display tab content).

I found that it shows fallback only the first time the page is loading. When you change the tab it does not trigger any suspense events (pending, resolve, or fallback).

I guess that it's something relative to vue-router, but I can get how I can adjust it to work properly. Would be appreciated any help.

There are the main parts of the code (full code can be [found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-suspense-with-router-bug-fexwn3)).

*Parent component with tabs*

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <Suspense
          :timeout="0"
          @pending="log('pending')"
          @resolve="log('resolve')"
          @fallback="log('fallback')"
        >
          <component :is="Component"></component>
          <template #fallback> Loading... </template>
        </Suspense>
      </router-view>
```

*Router*

```
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    redirect: { name: "UserList" },
    children: [
      {
        path: "users",
        component: { render: () => h(RouterView) },
        children: [
          {
            path: "",
            name: "UserList",
            component: UserList
          },
          {
            path: "profile",
            name: "Profile",
            component: Profile
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Ok, so reason is in this line
```component: { render: () => h(RouterView) },```
Sadly, i need to properly handle my routes as I want:(